Frequency resolution in STFT
In the textbooks I've read and also in this answer the STFT of a signal $x[k]$ with length $N$ ($N$ is the number of samples in $x$) using a window $w[k]$ with length $L$ is defined as
$$X[k,r] = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}x[m+k]w[m]e^{-jr\Omega_0 k}, \ \ \ \Omega_0 = \frac{2\pi}{N} \tag1$$
or
$$X[k,r] = \sum_{m=0}^{L-1}x[m+k]w[m]e^{-jr\Omega_0 k}, \ \ \ \Omega_0 = \frac{2\pi}{N} \tag2$$
My question is, why do we set the frequency resolution equal to $\frac{2\pi}{N}$ and not set it $\Omega_0 = \frac{2\pi}{L}$? As far as I understand it, in the STFT we perform the DFT of a section of length $L$ of the original signal $x[m+k]w[m]$. This would also explain why a longer window length provides a finer frequency resolution, as opposed to $\frac{2\pi}{N}$ which is fixed regardless of window length. But why do the formulas use the entire length of $x[k]$ for the spectral resolution instead of just the length of signal we are performing the DFT on?

You need to define $N$ for the question to make sense

@Hilmar $N$ is the length (number of samples) of $x[k]$. I mention that in the first sentence.

Sorry, I overlooked this.

The $N$ defining the full signal length is not the same as the $N$ in the STFT equation, which defines the DFT length.
The STFT is a sliding DFT so the only value that matters is the latter.
Without zero-padding, each windowed DFT has length indeed equal to $L$.
